# Alter div padding or margins only when element falls at top of page

Tags: css, css-paged-media

I'm writing a book. My CSS styles for vertical spacing of various elements (chapter, section, subsection, etc.) work fine, except when the section, subsection, etc., element falls at the top of the page of paged-media. I can manually tweak the ones that are CURRENTLY at the top of a page, but any changes that reflow the text mess it up (move it off of the top of a page).

I'm hoping to find a selector that says, "If this element appears at the top of a page (following automatic or manual page break) then select it.

So far, all I have been able to do is use an additional class, e.g. "topofpage", which I stupidly manually add to an element.

Comment: What are you using to format your book to make pages?

Comment: I'm using Prince to process html.

Comment: Are you using margins or padding to create the space? Can you add a bit of your CSS so that we can see what is not currently working?

Comment: I am afraid you have missed the point. I'm looking for a way for the CSS to know when an element is at the top of a page via automatic pagebreak. If I could find a way to do this, I can code the CSS to behave as needed.